# Is there a way to get Telegram Channels messages programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, telegram

I'm trying to get programmatically messages from a public Telegram Channel.

Unfortunatly the channel isn't mine, so I'm not allowed to add a bot in it. In that case it would be able to get updates.

Do you know any way to do it?

Comment: Without bot access, your best bet would be to use the Telegram API documented here:
https://core.telegram.org/methods. Without knowing more about Telegram's implementation details and your specific use case, I suspect the call you need is messages.getHistory.

Comment: Your question appears to be too broad and if so may be off-topic for SO.  Consider adding some code showing what you have tried so far. [ask].  Good luck!